# test failes when 0 is next each other - Leetcode 283. Move Zeroes problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, splice

I was working on the leetcode 283. move zeroes question but I got a weird test failure when there is 0 next to another 0.

Below is my code.

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {void} Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
 */
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {

    let i = 0;
    while(i < nums.length){
        if(nums[i] == 0){
            nums.push(nums.splice(i, 1))
        }
        i++
    }
   
};
```

All the tests are passed while when 0 is next to 0, the test is failed.

Input
nums =
[0,0,1,3,12]
Output
[0,1,3,12,0]
Expected
[1,3,12,0,0]

Input
nums =
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
Output
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
Expected
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Could you please give me any clue where I missed?

Answer (score 1):

You're advancing the index and at the same time removing the previous element of the array, so you skip one each two consecutive zeroes.

Besides, as splice returns an array (not a single element) you're pushing an array, leaving the final array a little bit strange:

```js
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {

    let i = 0;
    while(i < nums.length){
        console.log('checking',i,' of ', nums.length,' value:',nums[i]);
        if(nums[i] == 0){
            nums.push(nums.splice(i, 1))
        }
        console.log('nums is now',nums);
        i++
    }
   
};

moveZeroes([0,0,1,3,12])
```

As a solution I would go with `filter` that allows you to separate the zero-values from the non-zero ones:

```js
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {

Object.assign(nums,nums.filter(x => x!=0).concat(nums.filter(x => x ==0)));

}

n1 = [0,0,1,3,12];
n2 = [0,0,0,0,0,1,0];

console.log(n1);
moveZeroes(n1);
console.log(n1);

console.log(n2);
moveZeroes(n2);
console.log(n2);
```

(in the near future we will have `group` , this will make unnecesary having several calls to `filter` for the classification)